# Robot request to an ASP.Net app

Tags: asp.net, web-crawler

Is there a way to determine if a http request to an ASP.Net application is made from a browser or from a robot/crawler? I need to differentiate this two kind of requests.

Thanks!

Comment: What will you do differently?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501514/how-to-detect-if-a-visitor-is-human-and-not-a-spider

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't. There is no fool proof to determine what originated a request - all HTTP headers can be spoofed.

Some crawlers (GoogleBot and such) do advertise themselves, but that doesn't mean a person browsing can't pretend to be GoogleBot.

The best strategy it to look for the well known bots (by `User-Agent` header and possibly by the known IP address) and assume those are crawlers.

Answer (score 1):

Well... If the robot want to be recognized as a robot, yes. Cause he can easilly simulates that he is a web browser.

Personnaly, I will use this list to start: http://www.robotstxt.org/db.html

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Request.Browser.Crawler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.crawler.aspx), but that only works for some crawlers.